# How to check if excel cell changed from picking dropdown option

Tags: excel, vba

In excel I have a cell, that does a list type (loading data from a column in another sheet). In vba code, I have the workbook change event. How can I detect if the change to the cell occured if I made a manual edit or selected an option in the dropdown list?

Comment: Out of interest, why?

Answer (score 2):

What about:

```
Private Sub Worksheet_Change(ByVal Target As Range)

If Target.Address = "$A$1" Then
    If ActiveCell.Address <> Target.Address Then
        MsgBox "Manually Typed"
    Else
        MsgBox "Chosen from list"
    End If
End If

End Sub
```

It's late and I might be wrong, but a chosen value from the list will keep the activecell to be the same as the target cell. Any manually typed value will only be effective after somehow changing the activecell.

Comment: When you click the dropdown arrow, that becomes the active cell.

Comment: Yes, @omega, that's the whole point. So it's the way to distinguish between manually typed value and clicked option

Comment: @omega, have you actually evaluated the code? When you manually type a value, you can only get the worksheet_change event to trigger when you somehow exit the cell. With a mouse click chosen value this won't happen. So in the first event, acticecell can never be the same as the target cell. Hence why this would always be a manually typed value

Comment: It doesn't allow to exit the cell, because there is column validation (i.e. list), and when the value doesn't matches a value in the list, it shows an error dialog asking to cancel or retry.

Comment: Yes offcourse, that's the point to using a list, I thought you asked the question because you want to distinquish between whether the value was manually typed or chosen from the list. I guess what you looking for then is A) stop error from showing > Tick the box in the data validation menu to stop this, B) do a check if the written or chosen value is in your validation list > `.Find` for example could do that for you.